# Read messages displayed in Unread inbox filter after clicking "Refresh"

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

Steps to reproduce:

1. tap on inbox icon
2. tap “mark all read”
3. select inbox (unread) // no messages in list now
4. tap “refresh” (tap “mark all read” if there’s no refresh link until it appears)
5. all READ messages are displayed, but the current mode of inbox is UNREAD.

> [image]

reproduced on iPadOS 16 and Android 13 as well. Both on Chrome browser.

Here's video proof on Android:

> [image: in action]

### UPD: Feb 1, 2023

Now it's harder to reproduce (since "mark all read" is grayed out when no unread messages), but still possible:

1. open inbox
2. mark single item as unread (envelope icon)
3. switch to "unread mode"
4. tap on "mark all read"

There's still item displayed, but it's read.

Comment: No repro when clicking the "Mark all read" on "Unread", but perhaps I missed other factors like having the "Refresh" button shown.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. which OS, browser you tried?

Comment: Chrome 109 on Windows 10.

Comment: Refresh means you want to see the messages, so it's expected they show up.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I disagree. Instead refreshing on recycle bin should considered as undelete. Nonsense!

Comment: I really have no idea what you mean. How recycle bin and undelete are related to anything here?

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars since "refresh" means refresh, not to change the view mode.

Comment: The refresh button is never showing up for me. No matter how many times I click "mark as read" in an empty "unread" inbox. (Step 4 in your list)

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the issue in Android 12, Chrome 109.0.5414.85

Comment: @Aaliyah mark some messages as read/unread by clicking the envelope near them, this will make the refresh button appear. I don't see any bug here, but feel free to experiment with what the OP reports. :-)

Comment: I tried toggling the read/unread status of some messages, but no matter what I do, there is still no “refresh” button. Perhaps that’s another bug?

Comment: Oh, I see: I have to do it from another tab. Then the refresh button appears, and yes, I can reproduce the bug as reported in the question. Firefox 109 on Linux.

Comment: @V2Blast clicking Refresh isn't really necessary step, see 1st Feb update. But on refreshing you'll see all notifications instead of some recently marked as unread. So there're probably two different issues with the similar outcome.